# Add row if id not exist else add to value in a cell

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql table named `Anonymat_Table` (two columns `Anonymat` and `Moyenne`). I need to add a row if `Anonymat` (`VarChar(45)`) doesn't exist. Else add value to cell `Moyenne`.

```
+----------+-----------+
| Anonymat |  Moyenne  |
+----------+-----------+
| EzBn142d |    12.00  |
+----------+-----------+
```

I'm building a WPF Project, I have a form with two textboxes and a button so if I click the button and write in the textboxes (EzBn142d and 2.00) it change the table to

```
+----------+-----------+
| Anonymat |  Moyenne  |
+----------+-----------+
| EzBn142d |    14.00  |
+----------+-----------+
```

And if I click the button after I enter in the textboxes (Nbdjm20DV and 4.00) it add a row in the table and will appear like this

```
+-----------+-----------+
| Anonymat  |  Moyenne  |
+-----------+-----------+
| EzBn142d  |   14.00   |
| Nbdjm20DV |    4.00   |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: One more thing missing: "And it actually should look like this:...."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ON DUPLICATE KEY. So the Primary key or a uniqe key must define on FIELD Anonymat.

**sample**

```
INSERT INTO Anonymat_Table (Anonymat,Moyenne) 
VALUE('bernd' , 13.99)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  Moyenne = Moyenne + VALUES(Moyenne);
```

**it also works with multirows like this**

```
INSERT INTO Anonymat_Table (Anonymat,Moyenne) 
VALUE
('bernd' , 13.99),
('tom' , 1.99),
('mark' , 3.95),
('anna' , 0.95)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  Moyenne = Moyenne + VALUES(Moyenne);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also use IF EXISTS to achieve what you want.

example:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Anonymat_Table WHERE Anonymat = anonymat)
    UPDATE Anonymat_Table
       SET [Moyenne] = moyenne + Moyenne
    WHERE Anonymat = anonymat
ELSE
    INSERT INTO Anonymat_Table
           ([Anonymat]
           ,[Moyenne])
     VALUES
           (anonymat
           ,moyenne)
```

In above example "Anonymat and Moyenne are column names" and "anonymat and moyenne are values from your program"